# why does android xml not let you use more than 2 different backgrounds for your different layouts?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

I have 3 activities which I want to use different backgrounds with. but when i do this i get this i get this error however if i only use different backgrounds on 2 activities then the app works

In the **logcat**:-

```
11-20 13:40:25.855: E/AndroidRuntime(849): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medepad.community_virtual_ward/com.medepad.community_virtual_ward.Temperature}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

the activities are called main welcome and temperature.

code for activity_main
xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/main" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.medepad.community_virtual_ward;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int a;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView start = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent welcome= new Intent (this,Welcome.class);
        startActivity(welcome);
    }
}
```

code for temperature

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/temperature" >

</LinearLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.medepad.community_virtual_ward;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Temperature extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.temperature);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

welcome xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/welcome" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
package com.medepad.community_virtual_ward;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        TextView next= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent temperature= new Intent(this, Temperature.class);
        startActivity(temperature);
    }
}
```

as you can see from the code i have set activity_main to have a backgrounds called main, activity welcome to have a background welcome and finally activity temperature to have a background temperature which are all in my drawable folders when i run this the app launches activity_main then a textview opens the next activity welcome. But when i click the next textview in welcome to open temperature I get the error above. However if i change the background of temperature to one of the earlier xml backgrounds like main or welcome. THE WHOLE APP WORKS. so lets be clear because no one has been able to solve this. The app works until I use a 3 different backgrounds.Try it yourself there must be a problem with android but if you get it to work paste your code here or tell me where the error is in my code. So why am i getting this error ?

Comment: The problem is definitely NOT in using 3 backgrounds... You can absolutely use many different backgrounds for many different activities.

Comment: then where is the problem?????????

Comment: Paste your @drawable/welcome, @drawable/temperature, @drawable/main files. I suspect @drawable/temperature is the problem...

Comment: Also using multiple question marks will not speed up solving your problem...

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess and say that you're background drawables are probably high-res images? If that's true, then somewhere in the stracktrace, you'll probably find an [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).

Comment: sorry smitalm it has been very frustrating for me i will paste the pictures for you now. how do i paste them here

Comment: Change your "temperature" background with some other background.Take some other image and try your code with those 3 different background.If it works, that means there is some problem with "temperature" image.

Comment: MH yes there is an out of memory error in my stacktrace. I did not know there would be a problem using high-res images as it lets me use 2 of them for 2 backgrounds. ok what do i need to do? can you change the image res in photoshop. what res do i need to change them to or what is the recomended resolution for android

Comment: made 3 simple colored backgrounds in in Photoshop zanky and saved them to my drawable file and i still get the same error when i want to open the last activity temperature? still saying OutOfMemoryError like mh said

Comment: @user2608169 idk how are your images encoded, but even simple color can eat a lot of memory if it has high resolution. What is the size of your images?

Comment: I think you are using high resolution images.Save your images for `Web And Devices`. You might be doing simple save operation. What is your image size and resolution?